# Android studio on Dell computer not seeing my android device

Tags: android-studio-3.6

I have problem that Android studio doesnt see my mobile. I connected to my mobile to PC by cable but my mobile see my PC like its in electric socket. I enabled developer mode and USB debugging but still, i see on mobile like it is connected to socket. I have Dell PC and it has their own method to connect mobile with pc through bluetooth but then Android studio cant see my mobile, even its connected by cable. So can you please help me how can I connect my mobile with Dell pc by cable? Or how can i see mobile in android studio if mobile is connected by blue tooth?

I would be really happy if someone help me. Thanks.

Martin

Comment: You have to install the drivers for your device. Search for adb, thats what you need.

Comment: I have all drivers which i can have, but my mobile still see pc as an electric socket. I tried everything to change that

Comment: Can you check it with adb inside console?